# Assign ajax html response content which include "id" can not be trigger?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I use the Viusal Studio 2015 and IE Browser to debug 。

First I click the hyperlink "AAA"，the trace debug enter the function '$("#HrefBtn_1").click(function ()' successfully

，and then ajax html response the "BBB" to assign to the  $('#formDefault_2')。

,and then I click the hyperlink "BBB"， the trace debug can not enter the function '$("#HrefBtn_2").click(function ()'

```
Default1.aspx=>

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default1.aspx.cs"     Inherits="Default1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {


      $("#HrefBtn_1").click(function () {


          $.ajax({
              url: 'Default1.aspx/GetDataTest',
              type: 'POST',
              data: JSON.stringify(),
              contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
              dataType: "json",      
              error: function (xhr) {
               },
              success: function (SuccessReturnVaule) {

                  var lsHTML;
                  lsHTML = "<a href='#' id='HrefBtn_2' rel='example'>BBB</a>";
                  $('#formDefault_2').html(lsHTML);
                  //$('#formDefault_2').append(lsHTML);
              }

          });



      });

      $("#HrefBtn_2").click(function () {

          var lsTemp;
          lsTemp = "Here!";

      });




   });

</script>     

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

         <div id="formDefault_1">
             <a href="#" id="HrefBtn_1" rel="example">AAA</a> 
         </div>

         <div id="formDefault_2">

         </div>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


Default1.aspx.cs=>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Collections;

public partial class Default1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetDataTest()
    {      
        return "";
    }


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the hyperlink added inside `` is dynamically added,so your `click` function will not work,you need to use `on()` instead:

```
$("#formDefault_2").on("click","#HrefBtn_2",function () {
      var lsTemp = "Here!";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the click not being triggered is, the element `#HrefBtn_2` added dynamically. So you should use `on` event to bind the click for the dynamically added dom or else you can bind the click event after the element is rendered into the html like below.

I have added a function as `bindButtonClick` which i will trigger after the html is appended to the page which will bind the click actions.

```
$(function() {
  $("#HrefBtn_1").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'Default1.aspx/GetDataTest',
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify(),
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      dataType: "json",      
      error: function (xhr) {
      },
      success: function (SuccessReturnVaule) {
          var lsHTML;
          lsHTML = "<a href='#' id='HrefBtn_2' rel='example'>BBB</a>";
          $('#formDefault_2').html(lsHTML);
          //$('#formDefault_2').append(lsHTML);
          bindButtonClick();
      }
   });
  });
  function bindButtonClick() {
    $("#HrefBtn_2").click(function () {
        var lsTemp;
      lsTemp = "Here!";
    });
  }
});
```